# Name of the inequality $|x|+|y| \geq |x+y|$?

Tags: inequality

> What is the name of the inequality $|x|+|y| \geq |x+y|$?

I remember seeing this inequality and thinking it was the triangle inequality, but that only holds if $x,y,z$ are the side lengths of a triangle and this holds for all real numbers? If so is there a name for this inequality?

Comment: Still called the "triangle" inequality.

Comment: Why is it called that?

Answer (score 0):

If $\bar{x}$, $\bar{y}$ are two vectors, $\bar{x}+\bar{y}$ is the vector representing the third side of the triangle when the tip of $\bar{x}$ touches the tail of $\bar{y}$.

(Look at the triangle law of adding vectors to get a sense of the respective directionalities).

The inequality translates as "Sum of lengths of two sides of a triangle is greater than length of the third side".